# How to send data from the express node.js server with socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am learning how to use node.js, express and socket.io.

I would like to send the results of a query in json format from the server to the clients every a range of time. I created the function `intervalFunc` to do that.

By the way it doesn't work.

This is my code in `index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();

//php package
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
    binPath: 'php'
  });

// set view engine to php-express
app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

// routing all .php file to php-express
app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);

//App setup
var server = app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('listening on requests on port 4000');
});

//Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Socket setup
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

    socket.on('typing', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    });

    
});

var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : 'xxx',
  database: "xxx"
});

connection.connect();

//function not working
function intervalFunc() {
    connection.query('SELECT prov_id, prov_nome FROM provincie', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err; //error
        console.log('The solution is:', rows);
        io.sockets.emit('query_res', rows);
      
    });
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 1500);

connection.end();
```

The error that I receive is located in the `if` inside the function that is `if (err) throw err;`.

This is the exception of the error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\socketio_project\index.js:60
        if (err) throw err;
                 ^

Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (C:\xampp\htdocs\socketio_project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:215:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\xampp\htdocs\socketio_project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)    
    at Connection.query (C:\xampp\htdocs\socketio_project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
    at Timeout.intervalFunc [as _onTimeout] (C:\xampp\htdocs\socketio_project\index.js:59:16)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT',
  fatal: false
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can help?

Comment: Could you post the exception of the `err` that is thrown, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `connection` is closed and then the `query` is send/ enqueued in the driver. Node.js is asynchron which means that the `connection.end` happens before the `connection.query`.

You could try something like this (only the relevant part is pasted here):

```js
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : 'xxx',
  database: "xxx"
});


//function not working
function intervalFunc() {
    connection.connect(); // <-- connect each time (maybe pool the connection?)

    connection.query('SELECT prov_id, prov_nome FROM provincie', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err; //error
        console.log('The solution is:', rows);
        io.sockets.emit('query_res', rows);
        connection.end(); // <-- close the connection here if the query was successful
      
    });
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 1500);

// no connection.end here <---
```

And it looks like the maintainer of the npm mysql package explain it in more details here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1296